# Excel form listbox issue when using locked property

Tags: excel, forms, vba, listbox, locked

I'm having an issue with the way a listbox behaves on an Excel form. Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Create a user form with one listbox control
- Use following code with this user form:

  ```
  Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
      Me.ListBox1.Locked = True
      Me.ListBox1.Locked = False
  End Sub

  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
      Dim i As Integer
      For i = 1 To 10
          Me.ListBox1.AddItem i
      Next i
  End Sub
  ```

When the form is first shown, I am able to navigate the list box normally, using arrow keys and page keys. However, after the double-click event is triggered, all keyboard navigation has no effect, including tabbing to other controls (if they're on the form). Clicking on the listbox does seem to work, and the focus outline is shown correctly, but there's something wrong with the way the focus is handled after the listbox is locked and then unlocked. What is going on?

Using Office 2013 32-bit edition.

Comment: Not that this is particularly helpful, but I am also using Office 2013 32-bit edition and this ran correctly for me in Excel.

Comment: You mean you were able to select items on the list box via keyboard after double-clicking?

Comment: @ A.S.H. Where'd your answer go? After trying your code, I noticed that making the listbox invisible moves the focus to the next control. If there's no control with the tab stop available, the focus "hangs" again, making the `.SetFocus` method of the listbox mandatory. So, it looks like the most reliable way to avoid this keyboard "hang up" is to move the focus to another control and then set it back to the listbox.

Comment: Yes, I was able to select items on the listbox using the keyboard after double-clicking.

Comment: @OpiesDad Huh, something is different then. Running Windows 7 32-bit at work and Office 2016 / Windows 10 64-bit at home, and it repeats itself 100% on both machines.

Comment: I tried it again with the worksheet I made before using your code and it now replicates the issue, so the keyboard does stop working.  I'm not sure why it did not have the issue before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to replicate this issue, and setting the focus somewhere else before locking and unlocking the listbox worked for me:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
     Me.TextBox1.SetFocus 'or some other control.
     Me.ListBox1.Locked = True
     Me.ListBox1.Locked = False
     Me.ListBox1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

2 solutions I tested that allows you to use Arrow Keys to navigate.

1. Given that there isn't a single click event handler, try call the Single Click Event after the DblClick (works all the time):

   ```
   Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
       Debug.Print "ListBox1_Click()"
   End Sub

   Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
       Debug.Print "ListBox1_DblClick()"
       With Me.ListBox1
           .Locked = True
           .Locked = False
       End With
       ListBox1_Click
   End Sub

   Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
       Dim i As Integer
       For i = 1 To 10
           Me.ListBox1.AddItem i
       Next i
   End Sub
   ```
2. Setting the `Cancel = False` at the end of DblClick. (Sometimes does not work!)

   ```
   Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
       Debug.Print "ListBox1_DblClick()"
       With Me.ListBox1
           .Locked = True
           .Locked = False
       End With
       Cancel = False
   End Sub

   Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
       Dim i As Integer
       For i = 1 To 10
           Me.ListBox1.AddItem i
       Next i
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Sorry, neither workaround has worked for me. The form remains unresponsive to the keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the zoom in the sheet that has the listbox worked for me.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim temp As Double
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Change worksheet zoom setting for the active window
temp = ActiveWindow.Zoom
ActiveWindow.Zoom = temp + 10
ActiveWindow.Zoom = temp
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```